# Can't reverse a sublist

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, reverse

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L[0:2] = [8, 9]
>>> L
[8, 9, 3, 4]
>>> L[0:2].reverse()
>>> L
[8, 9, 3, 4]
```

Can you explain for me why `L[0:2].reverse()` does not change the `L` list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`L[0:2]` creates a new copy of the list, and `L[0:2].reverse()` then reverses that copy. There is a big difference between using assignment to a slice, and to only reading a slice (calling a method, even one that mutates the object, does not turn this into assignment).

You could use slice assignment to assign a reversed copy:

```
L[:2] = L[1:None:-1]
```

or

```
L[:2] = reversed(L[:2])
```

This replaces the first 2 elements with those same elements in reverse order:

```
>>> L = [42, 81, 13, 7]
>>> L[:2] = L[1:None:-1]
>>> L
[81, 42, 13, 7]
>>> L[:2] = reversed(L[:2])
>>> L
[42, 81, 13, 7]
```

Also see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) for details on how this works.

Comment: I don't think so mate, when i type: L[0:2]=[8,9]. It did change the list L

Comment: @ĐạtNguyễnThành: Yes, because that's **assignment**. `L[0:2].reverse()` doesn't assign anything.